# ReactJS + Environment Variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

Just another React Question.
I want to store some URL information globally and divided by environment (dev, production etc...).

Searching on web, the usual method is .env files that are naturally supported by react.

I have create a .env and a .env.development so the first will be the production and the second the development file.

Inside the file, I put my configuration like:

```
# .env.development
REACT_APP_TEST=newyork
```

I tried to print the values with:

```
console.log(process.env);
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_TEST);
```

What I get is:

```
Object
  NODE_ENV:"development"
  PUBLIC_URL:""
```

The second is undefined.

Where is the problem?

Comment: This seems more like a node question than a react question

Comment: What fixed it for me was simply closing the terminal running my local dev server and re-running `npm run start`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using create-react-app, you will need to update your `env.js` to include your new environment variable in the build.

The function `getClientEnvironment(publicUrl)` sets the environment variables that get injected into the build for your use. Here, you can add your custom env variable like so:

```
  {
    // Useful for determining whether we’re running in production mode.
    // Most importantly, it switches React into the correct mode.
    NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
    // Useful for resolving the correct path to static assets in `public`.
    // For example, <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/img/logo.png'} />.
    // This should only be used as an escape hatch. Normally you would put
    // images into the `src` and `import` them in code to get their paths.
    PUBLIC_URL: publicUrl,
    CUSTOM: process.env.CUSTOM || 'fallback'
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

If you're not using CRA, you can use the [webpack DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) to do the same thing.

**UPDATE 2:**

**@DimitarChristoff** pointed out that you should use the `REACT_APP_*` format for declaring env variables. If you prepend your env variable with `REACT_APP_`, CRA will automatically pick it up and add it to the Webpack DefinePlugin:

```
// Grab NODE_ENV and REACT_APP_* environment variables and prepare them to be
// injected into the application via DefinePlugin in Webpack configuration.
const REACT_APP = /^REACT_APP_/i;
```

Comment: are you sure? `cross-env REACT_APP_TEST=FOO npm start` would make it available automagically. also, `env.js` has this: `// Grab NODE_ENV and REACT_APP_* environment variables and prepare them to be
// injected into the application via DefinePlugin in Webpack configuration.
const REACT_APP = /^REACT_APP_/i;` ...

Comment: @DimitarChristoff Nice, didn't know about that.

Comment: it probably is ignoring the file altogether. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env - he should try `.env.local` first and if that works, he needs to export `NODE_ENV` correctly to `development` to load `.env.development` i guess

Comment: I've tried .env.local but it is still undefined. Actually im developing using npm start. Im not compiling the app with a webpack script. And in don't have any env.js in my project folder.

Answer (score 3):

It was more simple than expected. 
The .env files has to be placed in the root of the project NOT in the SRC folder.

That's all!

Answer (score 1):

In general Webpack case, you can use webpack's [`DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) to define variables to be accessible across app.

In CRA (Create-React-App), you can add the environment variable in `env.js` file.

Using `env.js` is same as making your own `config.js` file where you create your config variable with a value either from `process.env` or use a default.